# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:′ not set up for use with LaTeX. 3′

Tags: packages, unicode, input-encodings

I get the **Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:′ not set up for use with LaTeX. 3′** when I am adding new items to my bibliography. I am using TexStudio. 
I tried to use Biber or BibTeX as a default bibliography tool, I also tried with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but nothing helps, the error appears even when I remove the inserted bibliography that caused the error in the first place.

What can I do to change this?

**Copy from the given "answer":**

There is no line of code producing error, that's the problem. I only get this error after inserting some, but not all bibliographies to the `.bib` file, even prior to citing them with `\cite` in the main `.tex` document. Apparently it can happen when I cite references containing a ' which is not accepted by the unicode. Perhaps a clash between unicode using by `.tex` and `.bib`? I am using a PhD thesis template with most of the packages installed already and a complicated multiple file structure so it is hard to navigate though it. Why would ' in references cause a problem? I read that using Biber allows using all encodings but I get the same error regardless if I use Biber or BibTeX to build my bibliography. Is there anything else I can change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's really impossible to answer without seeing an example of the code producing the error.

Comment: With the amount of information given, it is more than hard to say what is causing the issue. It might be the faulty input that biber wasn't happy about and recoded to strange stuff in the previous version. i vtc as unclear.